# Highcharts y-axis units on top

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis-labels, yaxis

I would like to add y-axis units on top of the y-axis.

For now I could use labels formatter and make the last label to be the unit. It works fine until I have just one label on y-axis. Then I get this:

[image]

And I would like to get this:

[image]

Do you have an idea of how to get it?

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ptbtvozb/2/

Code here:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                var unit = 'pop';
                if(this.isLast) {
                    return unit;
                } else {
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },
        tickInterval: 1,
        title: { text: "RQ-online" }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [[0, 1],[1, 1],[2, 1]]
    }]
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean by yAxis units? Do you want categories on the yAxis? Do you want unit suffixes? Do you want the last series to be a category and not a number?

Comment: I want the unit to be displayed at the end of y-axis, just like on the second image. Look here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/k3u7qz6f/2/ The last label of the y-axis is the unit of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [yAxis.title](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title):

```
yAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'pop',
    align: 'high',
    offset: 0,
    rotation: 0,
    y: -10
  },
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/akLc93mh/

Comment: That would be a great workaround, but I need the title for the title of the yAxis. It's already taken. I forgot to add it to the example. I'll fix it. Any other possibility that you can see?

Comment: You can still use the title to style seperate part of it  http://jsfiddle.net/gkhzw2s8/ If it is still not flexible enough, you should use [renderer.text](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text) to render a custom text on the chart.